# How to push data from SQL to HDFS

Tags: etl, sqoop, bigdata

I have the following use case:
We have several SQL databases in different locations and we need to load some data them to HDFS.
The problem is that we do not have access to the servers from our Hadoop cluster(due to security concerns), but we can push data to our cluster.
Is there ant tool like Apache Sqoop to do such bulk loading.

Comment: Dump your table data in form of csv and using a custom program just push those csv content into hadoop. Sqoop is a better choice and widely used. Also check cascading jdbc for import function.

Comment: Running Sqoop requires *(a)* a Hadoop client i.e. a smorgasbord of JARs *(b)* the config files to reach your cluster i.e. `*-site.xml` in a directory that's in your CLASSPATH *(c)* the Sqoop JARs *(d)* all JDBC drivers that you need

Comment: Nowadays you can also use Spark to run JDBC-to-Hadoop-files ETL jobs -- plus any kind of cleansing/transformation that you care to develop in scala or python. That would require *(a)* the Spark runtime "with Hadoop 2.6 included" *(b)* the config files to reach the cluster plus a Spark env variable pointing to that dir *(c)* the JDBC drivers *(d)* enough RAM on the cluster

Answer (score 0):

Dump data as files from your SQL databases in some delimited format for instance csv and then do a simple hadoop put command and put all the files to hdfs.

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume I am working in a small company on 30 node cluster daily 100GB data processing. This data will comes from the different sources like RDBS such as Oracle, MySQL, IBMs Netteza, DB2 and etc. We need not to install SQOOP on all 30 nodes. The minimum number of nodes should be isntalled by SQOOP is=1. After installing on one machine now we will access those machines. Using SQOOP we will import that data. 
As per the security is considered no import will be done untill and unless the administartor has to put the following two commands.
MYSQL>grant all privileges on mydb.table to ''@'IP Address of Sqoop Machine'

MYSQL>grant all privileges on mydb.table to '%'@'IP Address of Sqoop Machine'
these two commands should be fire by admin. 
Then we can use our sqoop import commands and etc.